# How to fix "Unterminated regular expression literal" error when using replace()

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, format

I was trying to format currency input with 1000 separator and 2 decimal places upon typing using jQuery/JS but got this "Unterminated regular expression literal" error in 2 place, I have tried multiple ways to fix this but all leads to a dead end. Thanks a lot for helping!

```
//format fee amount number with commas on keyup (hopeless hotfix)
        $('#Fee_Amount_' + i).keyup(function(event) {
            //// skip for arrow keys
            if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

            //// format number
            $(this).val(function (index, value) {
                return value.replace(/(?!\.)\D/g, "").replace(/(?<=\..*)\./g, "").replace(/(?<=\.\d\d).*/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
            });
            


        });
        //end format
```

[here's my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb7Go.png)

Comment: We can not copy and paste from an image. Post the code

Comment: [well it has an error](https://regexper.com/#%2F%28%3F%3C%3D%5C..*%29%255C.%2Fg) Are you actually trying to match `?` What exactly do you think that reg exp is doing?

Comment: What are you trying to test for? Avoid using positive lookbehind  in JS, as it has not got good browser support

Comment: @epascarello i posted the code! Sorry this is my 1st time posting!

Comment: Yes, lookbehind is only supported on very recent JS features, and if I remember correctly, it is only supported in Chrome

Comment: AH, not enough coffee.. was not thinking about lookbehind.... :) And replacing as a person types is normally a bad bad idea.

Comment: Also, `event.which` is deprecated as well. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which

Comment: hmm after your suggestion i temporary fix it with this, kinda dumb but it works for now! i think there are better solutions to this... Thank you all for your reply! i still not understand fully but i will look into it..
`$(this).val(function (index, value) {
                    return value.replace(/(?!\.)\D/g, "").replace(/(\..*)\./g, "").replace(/(\.\d\d\d).*/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                });`